# Is it correct to space and not capitalize the first letter in incollection?

Tags: bibliographies, ieeetran

Is it correct to space and not capitalize the first letter of newtonian as done below? It looks a bit odd to me but I also don't know the norms.

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=normalsize,labelfont=sf,textfont=sf]{subfig}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{url}

%\usepackage{cite}
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor IEEE-Xplore}
% updated with editoria

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{bibi.bib}
@incollection{HARRISON19971,
title = {1 - Newtonian Mechanics},
editor = {H.R. Harrison and T. Nettleton},
booktitle = {Advanced Engineering Dynamics},
publisher = {Butterworth-Heinemann},
address = {London},
pages = {1-20},
year = {1997},
isbn = {978-0-340-64571-0},
doi = {https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-034064571-0/50001-1},
url = {https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780340645710500011},
author = {H.R. Harrison and T. Nettleton}
}

\end{filecontents*}
\newpage
%
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,bibi.bib}

\vspace{11pt}
\end{document}
```

Link: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780340645710500011

Comment: Off-topic: You should replace `H.R. Harrison` with `H. R. Harrison`. This informs BibTeX's parser that the person has two given names, not just one. See the screenshot you posted for an example of what happens if you write `H.R.` instead of `H. R.`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Englisn -- not sure about all other languages -- the first letters of personal, place and country names -- as well as of adjectives derived from these names -- are almost invariably capitalized. Tnus: Brown, Brownian motion, Newton, Newtonian mechanics, Germany, German engineering, England, English language, India, Indian rupee, Mexico, Mexican cuisine, etc.

Your document appears to use the `IEEEtran` bibliography style, which instructs BibTeX to apply so-called "English sentence style" to the `title` and certain other fields. In sentence style, all letters of all words, with the exception of the first letter of the first word, in a given field are converted to lowercase automatically.

This setting naturally requires authors to "protect" any words that should *not* be converted to all-lowercase by encasing them in an extra pair of curly braces. Thus, do replace

```
title = {1 - Newtonian Mechanics},
```

with

```
title = {1 - {Newtonian} Mechanics},
```